# How to find best constants matching numerical solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I have a function like follows,

$\psi(x) = A\,\psi_1(x) + B \,\psi_2(x)$

I have a full numerical solution for $\psi(x)$, I want to provide an analytical solution to $\psi(x)$ by finding suitable constants $A$ and $B$ to match analytical functions $\psi_1(x)$ and $\psi_2(x)$ to the numerical solution.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: I'd try to match asymptotic behavior at singularities, Taylor terms at zeros, etc.  If that didn't work (if, say, there *are* no "special" $x$ values in this loose sense) I might try to fit $A$ and $B$ by least squares, based on a grid of sampled $x$ values.

Comment: I think for this case I want to match asymptotic behavior at the singularity. Can you please point me to a resource, to learn it?

Comment: I assume your $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are built up out of familiar special functions, whose asymptotics can be found in (say) Olver's textbook or the NIST handbooks.  You have numerical access to $\psi$, so you can compute things like $\log \psi(x)/\log x$ and so on for $x$ near the singularity, and compare what you get to theory.  It's a bit hard to describe in the abstract, as it's more art (or craft) than science, and you have given no detail about your particular functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the *simplest* way of doing this would just be to use least-squares or some other simple data fitting method; since you have a numerical solution for $\psi(x)$ then you only have a finite number of points $\{x_i\}$ for which you know $\psi(x)$, then just fit
$$
\min_{A, B} \sum_i \left(\psi(x_i) - A\psi_1(x_i) - B\psi_2(x_i)\right)^2.
$$

Additionally, if there are particular points you care about, you can reweight those in the objective to minimize their loss instead by some weights $w_i\ge 0$ (e.g. if you care that points $x_3, x_4$ are very close to correct, say, because they're near some asymptote you care about, then make $w_3, w_4$ large):

$$
\min_{A, B} \sum_i w_i\left(\psi(x_i) - A\psi_1(x_i) - B\psi_2(x_i)\right)^2.
$$

Note that both of these problems have analytic solutions and many packages which can do the fitting for you (see, e.g., scikit-learn).